# ADF Copy Data activity fails with a misleading error message

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a tab-delimited txt file that has 1.8 million rows. I am converting the txt file to parquet on the azure datalake storage.

ADF throws an error when reading a line around 505k line; however when I split the file into 3 files with 600k lines, everything goes through without any problem.

I was wondering if this is a bug and anyone has encountered this before and if so, whether there is a workaround to convert the file in one shot instead of splitting?

[image]

**this is the error message:**

> found more columns than expected column count 156

Comment: I tried with around million rows It is working for me. for the error you are getting try using `fault tolerance` and check which rows are causing error and why. make sure your data is correct and appropriate.

Comment: I used fault tolerance and there is 3-4k rows that cause problems, though it is not clear why those rows are considered incompatible when running a large file and not in parts

Comment: Share the sample records which are getting failed

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot, NDA issues

Comment: This sounds like a data related issue. Looks like few of your source records are having incorrect column delimiter which is resulting in the above error. Since you know the fault records you may try ingesting that file data (you will have to massage/prep the data by removing unwanted records for smooth testing) to an Azure SQL table using a copy activity in ADF by making sure that you choose the auto create table option in copy settings that way you will be able to visualize the data formatting and get better understanding on how to fix the source data.